# Why I cannot call setSomething()?

Tags: java, netbeans

I dont know how to acces my method of my class ProjectNode, that is returned from ExplorerManager mgr like this:

```
mgr.getRootContext().setSomething()
```

getRootContext() returns Node object, but I put class ProjectNode (extends AbstractNode, abstractNode extends Node)into rootContext.

The compiler does not want to eat that line of code. But it must!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((ProjectNode)mgr.getRootContext()).setSomething();
```

don't forget to check type!

Answer (score 3):

If `getRootContext()` returns a `Node`, then you can only call the methods defined in `Node`, not in its subclasses. You can cast the return value to another class if you need that:

```
Node rootContext = mgr.getRootContext();
if(rootContext instanceof ProjectNode){
    ProjectNode rootProjectNode = (ProjectNode)rootContext;
    rootProjectNode.setSomething();
} else {
    //handle this case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If`setSomething()` is not a public method on `Node` class, you can not "feed the compiler" that code - no matter how you try.
As all the wise men has spoken above, you must cast the result to the subclass that defines your `setSomething()` method.